# How to approach this eigenvalue problem under this specific normalization circumstance?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

We have the classic system
\begin{align}
&y''(x) + \lambda y(x) = 0\\
&y(0) = y(L) = 0, L >0
\end{align}
but must be solved under the condition that
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{L} |y(x)|^2 dx = 1.
\end{align}

Of course, solving the system we get
\begin{align}
y(x) = c_1 \sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x) + c_2 \cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x).
\end{align}

From the first condition we have
\begin{align}
y(0) = 0 \implies c_2 = 0.
\end{align}

From the second condition, we get
\begin{align}
y(L) = 0 \implies c_1 \sin (\sqrt{\lambda} L)= 0.
\end{align}

Taking the integral condition, we get
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{L} c_1^2 \sin^{2}(\sqrt{\lambda}x)dx = 1 &\implies \int_{0}^{L} \sin^{2}(\sqrt{\lambda}x)dx = \dfrac{1}{c_1^2}\\
&\implies \ldots\\
&\implies c_1^2 = \dfrac{4\lambda}{2L \sqrt{\lambda} - \sin(2L \sqrt{\lambda})}.
\end{align}

Which does not amount to much.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $\sin (\sqrt{\lambda} L)= 0\iff\sqrt{\lambda} L\in\pi\Bbb Z.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tacitly assumed that $\lambda>0$. You should also consider the cases $\lambda=0,$ which gives you $y=ax+b$ and $\lambda<0$, which gives you $y=c_1e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}x}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}.$

Comment: Thanks for noticing! Will do!